# Resizing Problems of Thumbnail Caption

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with the resizing of thumbnail captions
In line three I want "2012" aligned to the left and "1.Preis" aligned to the right.
The first thing I don't understand is it seems I only have 10 columns to work with. When i try to use col-md-offset-10 "1.Preis" jumps into the next line.

Here is also a bootply code example. http://bootply.com/82887
As you can see when you try to resize the window (before it goes into tablet size mode) "1.Preis" will leave the thumbnail border.

```
<div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>Wohnprojekt Eggenberger Gürtel</p>
                    <p>Graz-Gries</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p>2012</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-8"><p>1.Preis</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>Gutachterverfahren Kalsdorf-Siro</p>
                    <p>Kalsdorf</p>
                    <p>2011</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>Gutachterverfahren Kalsdorf-Siro</p>
                    <p>Kalsdorf</p>
                    <p>2011</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>Gutachterverfahren Kalsdorf-Siro</p>
                    <p>Kalsdorf</p>
                    <p>2011</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use floats to get the appearance you want:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
    <div class="caption">
        <p>Wohnprojekt Eggenberger Gürtel</p>
        <p>Graz-Gries</p>
        <p style="float:left;">2012</p>
        <p style="text-align:right;">1.Preis</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://bootply.com/82890)